# Bash for loop syntax error with pipe

Tags: bash

I'm trying this command

```
for x in qstat -u '*' | grep Eqw | awk {'print $1'}; do qmod -cj $x; done
```

and end up with this error:

```
-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `|'
```

I've tried wrapping my qstat command in various quotes and brackets to no avail, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since you seem to want to loop through on the result, so change it to:

```
for x in `qstat -u '*' | grep Eqw | awk {'print $1'}`; do qmod -cj $x; done
```

Answer (score 5):

An optimised version will be :

```
for x in $(qstat -u '*' | awk '/Eqw/{print $1}'); do qmod -cj "$x"; done
```

- the backquote (`) is used in the old-style command substitution. The foo=$(command) syntax is recommended instead. Backslash handling inside $() is less surprising, and $() is easier to nest. See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/082
- `awk` can grep hitself

Answer (score 0):

Use this sript instead:

```
for x in $(qstat -u * | awk '/Eqw/ {print $1}')
do
    qmod -cj $x
done
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be:

```
for x in $(qstat -u '*' | grep Eqw | awk '{print $1}'); do qmod -cj $x; done
```